# Win7 moving files and folders from dir to dir makes all my files empty

Tags: windows-7, windows, file-transfer

I have read [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/408089/how-i-can-recover-files-when-the-folder-shows-empty-but-the-files-are-not-delete?newreg=ccb41d5a7cdb41aab073d69bcf3ab38c) but it's not the same issue. I am facing a critical problem. I lost all my source codes. The causes :

I logged in my user account, i noticed that windows created a new user folder named `\Users\Temp\`, I don't know why. Trying to repair that I moved all data from the first valid user folder `\Users\MY_USER` to a new one i created as `admin user`. Now when I log in my new user, I can see all the folders and files from the first account, but my files are `EMPTY`.

Comment: If the files were not deleted but overwritten with 0's there is little you can do except use your backups to restore them.

Comment: backups ? do you mean System Backup and Restore of win7 ! will i get my data back doing this, i haven't tried that yet.

Comment: By backups I mean copies of your data on another storage device.  The question you linked to was caused by a virus, you seem to have indicated, you also were infected with a malicious file.  **In the end the fact your files are not empty indicates the original files are gone.**

Answer (score 1):

See this article that contains some fixes :

[How to Fix Temporary Profile in Windows 7](http://www.sysprobs.com/fix-temporary-profile-windows-7)
[Temporary User Profiles](http://helgeklein.com/blog/2011/11/temporary-user-profiles/)

Comment: thank you @harrymc for your answer. But i already have copied the files from older to new user. the former user is no more used, is it possible to recover my files ?!

Comment: If the files were deleted, look in the Recycle Bin. If you are unlucky there, try to search for previous versions: see [this article](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/recover-lost-or-deleted-files). Don't do any large deletes on the disk until/if you manage to recover the files.